# Need To Convert Text To UpperCase and Lowercase When Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know nothing about JavaScript, and I'm sure this is an easy thing to do, but I've been bashing my brain for the past three hours trying to figure it out.

What I want is to have some text, say Test.com, that when clicked will transform all the letters to uppercase (TEST.COM).  If the user clicks again, the text will go to all lowercase(text.com).  On the third click the text goes back to the original form (Test.com).

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I found this, http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/text/case-uppercase.html, but it just goes to uppercase, and you have to click the button.  Can't figure out how to make it go to all lowercase, and then back to the original.

Comment: `toLowerCase()` will take it lower. You need to store the original text in a variable

Comment: Okay.  How would I go about that?  :/

Comment: You will need to store the state of the text in a variable so you know whether to toggle between uppercase or lowercase or original.

Comment: Why store original text? what about text-transform in css?

Comment: How do I make the text-transform in css when the link is clicked.  I have NO knowledge of JavaScript.

Comment: I have provided a solution that changes the button caption from change upper to change lower and vice versa, along with along with giving the required code. You can keep doing it as long as you want not just 3 times.

Comment: @BillyW did you try my answer? if you are taking out only script then do not forget to add id to you controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the long-winded vanilla JS version:

```
// grab the element containing the text
var div = document.querySelector('#test');

// grab the text
var text = div.innerHTML;

// save a copy of the text
var originalText = div.innerHTML;

// set `toggle` to O for original
// L = lowercase, U = uppercase
var toggle = 'O';

// add an click listener to the element containing the text
div.addEventListener('click', function () {

    // toggle between the states updating the text
    // of the element with each new click
    switch (toggle) {
            case 'O':
            div.innerHTML = text.toUpperCase();
            toggle = 'U';
            break;
        case 'U':
            div.innerHTML = text.toLowerCase();
            toggle = 'L';
            break;
        case 'L':
            div.innerHTML = originalText;
            toggle = 'O';
            break;
    }
}, false)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w234hvdv/10/)

And if you wanted to get this working for multiple instances of text on the page, something like this would work. Ideally you'd want to use event propagation for this, but since the layout of your page might change in the future it's probably not worth the risk:

```
;(function () {

    // grab all the elements
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

    // status is used to keep track of where in the cycle each text item is
    var status = {};

    for (var i = 0, l = divs.length; i < l; i++) {

        var div = divs[i];
        var key = div.innerHTML.toLowerCase();

        // update the status object with the initial text values
        status[key] = {
            status: 'O',
            originalText: div.innerHTML
        };

        // add the listener like last time
        // except this time we monitor the status object for
        // for each text instance
        div.addEventListener('click', function () {
            var text = this.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
            var key = status[text].originalText.toLowerCase();
            var toggle = status[key].status;
            var originalText = status[key].originalText;
            switch (toggle) {
                case 'O':
                    this.innerHTML = originalText.toUpperCase();
                    status[key].status = 'U';
                    break;
                case 'U':
                    this.innerHTML = originalText.toLowerCase();
                    status[key].status = 'L';
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    this.innerHTML = status[key].originalText;
                    status[key].status = 'O';
                    break;
            }
        }, false);
    }

}());
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w234hvdv/51/)

Comment: How do I make this work in WordPress?  I just add the above code to the <head></head> within a <script> tag?

Comment: You're best off adding this in script tags but just before the `</body>` tag, otherwise you'd have to introduce a listener to check if the DOM is ready.

Comment: One more quick question, is there a way to make this work for multiple words on one page?  Here's a link to my site:  http://domaintricity.com/

It works for the first domain name but not the others.  :/

Comment: [Here's a really rubbish version I've hacked together](http://jsfiddle.net/w234hvdv/42/). I'm sure it can be improved, but I've got to go home now :)

Comment: @BillyW, I've updated the answer with a tidied up version of the above code.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var count = 1;
$('.text').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('uppercase', count === 2);
  $(this).toggleClass('lowercase', count === 3);
  if (count === 3) {
    count = 0
  }
  count++;

});
```

```css
.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.lowercase {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="text">CamelCase 1 </span>
```

Comment: You can either use a CSS class which should do the trick or you can use the JS function to uppercase.

Comment: Did you read the whole question? Uppercase, then lowercase, then original... This only solves a third of the whole question.

Comment: Ok. It's a good start, but make sure you post *complete* answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Define 2 CSS classes.

```
.ucase {text-transform:uppercase;}
.lcase {text-transform:lowercase;}
```

Use a combination of jQuery [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to switch the cases.

Remove all classes from the text to return to original state.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".textitem").click(function() {

       $t = jQuery(this);
        if($t.hasClass("ucase")) {
            $t.removeClass("ucase").addClass("lcase");
        } else if($t.hasClass("lcase")) {
            $t.removeClass("lcase");
        } else {
            $t.addClass("ucase");
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ptj1ke8y/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but you can count the clicks (modulus 3), and adjust the text according to the number and cycle through your 3 cases.

```js
var i = 0;
var cl = $('#text').text();
$('#text').click(function() {
  var str = $(this).text();
  if (i % 3 == 0) {
    $('#text').html(str.toUpperCase());
  }
  if (i % 3 == 1) {
    $('#text').html(str.toLowerCase());
  }
  if (i % 3 == 2) {
    $('#text').html(cl);
  }
  i++
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toUpperCase()` and `.toLowerCase()` JavaScript methods to change the case of any text.

Since you're using jQuery then you can use the `.text()` jQuery method to get and set the text content of any DOM node.

You need to store somewhere the original value of your text so that you can get it after the third click, and the jQuery `.data()` method would be good for this because that way you can easily have few elements on one page that behaves this way.

You can write something like this to make all elements with class "test" behave in a way that you have described:

```
  $('.test').click(function () {

    var $this = $(this),
        data = $this.data('clicker');

    if (!data || !data.text) {
      data = {
        text: [
          $this.text(),
          $this.text().toUpperCase(),
          $this.text().toLowerCase()
        ],
        step: 0
      };
    }
    data.step = (data.step + 1) % 3;
    $this.text(data.text[data.step]);
    $this.data('clicker', data);

  });
```

See: [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/soquberabo/3/edit) for an example of how it works with 3 elements simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want (button caption changes to tell what is it going to do and changes the text):

```
        <form name="form1" method="post">
    <input name="instring" id="instring" type="text" value="this is the text string" size="30">
    <input type="button" id="button" name="Convert" value="Make Uppercase >>" onClick="makeUppercase();">
    <input name="outstring" type="text" id="outstring" value="" size="30">
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>


       function makeUppercase(){
           if( $('#button').val()=="Make Uppercase >>"){
                $('#button').attr("value","Make Lowercase >>");
                $('#outstring').attr('value', $('#instring').attr('value').toUpperCase());
           } else if($('#button').val()=="Make Lowercase >>") {
               $('#button').attr("value","Make Original >>");
               $('#outstring').attr('value', $('#instring').attr('value').toLowerCase());
           } else{
               $('#button').attr("value","Make Uppercase >>");
               $('#outstring').attr('value', $('#instring').attr('value'));
           }
       }
    </script>
```

Comment: How does this code get the text back to the original state?

Comment: @Andy updated code to have original also considered.

Answer (score 0):

First use **click()** to event handler to the "click" and then use **.hasClass()**, **removeClass()** and **addClass()** to do and use css **text-transform**

HTML file

```
<div id="trigger">click me to transform</div>
```

CSS File

```
.uppercase { text-transform: uppercase; }
.lowercase { text-transform:lowercase; }
```

Javascript file

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $( "#trigger" ).click(function() {
      if($( "#trigger" ).hasClass( "uppercase" )) {
           $(this).removeClass('uppercase').addClass('lowercase');
      }
      else {
          $(this).removeClass('lowercase').addClass('uppercase');
      }
   });
});
```

Try to play the [Sandbox](http://jsfiddle.net/athivvat/sr4u04hp/)